# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment while using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i have run below command in foor loop to get the html data of myurl

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("myurl").get();
```

when i am using above code i got below error

> ```
>  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
>  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2bd695c76c, pid=12495, tid=0x00007f2bd4863700
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
>  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>  Problematic frame:
>  V  [libjvm.so+0x99876c]  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_to_survivor_space<false>(oopDesc*)+0x7c
>
> Core dump written. Default location: /home/cardekho/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/bin/core or core.12495
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>  /home/cardekho/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/bin/hs_err_pid12495.log
>
>  If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>    http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> ```

Comment: This is seems to be the issue (for Open JDK): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179218.  It claims to be fixed.  What is your Java version? Please show us your loop (use [Edit])